# Center rotating circle to the page

Tags: html, css, rotation, css-animations, center

I want to center these rings to the center of the page.
The concentric circles seems to move and not stay fixed with the same center. 
I can't understand if the center is moving.
I want to keep it fixed to the center of the page.
I can't understand if the radius is changing.
Probably they're just fixed to a center and then translated of some pixels.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 100%;
}

.orbit {
  /*background: #090c29;*/
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.orbit-icon {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  font-size: 0.1em;
  border-radius: 100%;
  /*background: #ccc;
  color: #fff;*/
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.orbit-wrap {
  height: 50em;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.orbit-wrap>li {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/*.orbit-wrap > li:hover ul {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #fff;
}
.orbit-wrap > li:hover ~ li ul {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.orbit-wrap > li:hover ~ li ul li {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

ul[class^=ring] {
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
ul[class^=ring] li {
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}*/

.ring-00 {
  width: 40em;
  height: 40em;
  -webkit-animation: counterClockwiseRotate 35s linear infinite;
  animation: counterClockwiseRotate 35s linear infinite;
}

.ring-00 i {
  -webkit-animation: counterClockwiseRotate 35s linear infinite;
  animation: counterClockwiseRotate 35s linear infinite;
}

.ring-00>*:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) translate(25em) rotate(-30deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg) translate(25em) rotate(-30deg);
}

.ring-00>*:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg) translate(25em) rotate(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(60deg) translate(25em) rotate(-60deg);
}

.ring-00>*:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(25em) rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(25em) rotate(-90deg);
}

.ring-00>*:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg) translate(25em) rotate(-120deg);
  transform: rotate(120deg) translate(25em) rotate(-120deg);
}

.ring-00>*:nth-of-type(5) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg) translate(25em) rotate(-150deg);
  transform: rotate(150deg) translate(25em) rotate(-150deg);
}

.ring-00>*:nth-of-type(6) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(25em) rotate(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(25em) rotate(-180deg);
}

.ring-00>*:nth-of-type(7) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(210deg) translate(25em) rotate(-210deg);
  transform: rotate(210deg) translate(25em) rotate(-210deg);
}

.ring-00>*:nth-of-type(8) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg) translate(25em) rotate(-240deg);
  transform: rotate(240deg) translate(25em) rotate(-240deg);
}

.ring-00>*:nth-of-type(9) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(25em) rotate(-270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(25em) rotate(-270deg);
}

.ring-00>*:nth-of-type(10) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg) translate(25em) rotate(-300deg);
  transform: rotate(300deg) translate(25em) rotate(-300deg);
}

.ring-00>*:nth-of-type(11) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg) translate(25em) rotate(-330deg);
  transform: rotate(330deg) translate(25em) rotate(-330deg);
}

.ring-00>*:nth-of-type(12) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(25em) rotate(-360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg) translate(25em) rotate(-360deg);
}

.ring-0 {
  width: 30em;
  height: 30em;
  -webkit-animation: clockwiseRotate 35s linear infinite;
  animation: clockwiseRotate 35s linear infinite;
}

.ring-0 i {
  -webkit-animation: counterClockwiseRotate 35s linear infinite;
  animation: counterClockwiseRotate 35s linear infinite;
}

.ring-0>*:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) translate(20em) rotate(-30deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg) translate(20em) rotate(-30deg);
}

.ring-0>*:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg) translate(20em) rotate(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(60deg) translate(20em) rotate(-60deg);
}

.ring-0>*:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(20em) rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(20em) rotate(-90deg);
}

.ring-0>*:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg) translate(20em) rotate(-120deg);
  transform: rotate(120deg) translate(20em) rotate(-120deg);
}

.ring-0>*:nth-of-type(5) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg) translate(20em) rotate(-150deg);
  transform: rotate(150deg) translate(20em) rotate(-150deg);
}

.ring-0>*:nth-of-type(6) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(20em) rotate(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(20em) rotate(-180deg);
}

.ring-0>*:nth-of-type(7) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(210deg) translate(20em) rotate(-210deg);
  transform: rotate(210deg) translate(20em) rotate(-210deg);
}

.ring-0>*:nth-of-type(8) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg) translate(20em) rotate(-240deg);
  transform: rotate(240deg) translate(20em) rotate(-240deg);
}

.ring-0>*:nth-of-type(9) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(20em) rotate(-270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(20em) rotate(-270deg);
}

.ring-0>*:nth-of-type(10) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg) translate(20em) rotate(-300deg);
  transform: rotate(300deg) translate(20em) rotate(-300deg);
}

.ring-0>*:nth-of-type(11) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg) translate(20em) rotate(-330deg);
  transform: rotate(330deg) translate(20em) rotate(-330deg);
}

.ring-0>*:nth-of-type(12) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(20em) rotate(-360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg) translate(20em) rotate(-360deg);
}

.ring-1 {
  width: 20em;
  height: 20em;
  -webkit-animation: counterClockwiseRotate 30s linear infinite;
  animation: counterClockwiseRotate 30s linear infinite;
}

.ring-1 i {
  -webkit-animation: counterClockwiseRotate 30s linear infinite;
  animation: counterClockwiseRotate 30s linear infinite;
}

.ring-1>*:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) translate(15em) rotate(-30deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg) translate(15em) rotate(-30deg);
}

.ring-1>*:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg) translate(15em) rotate(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(60deg) translate(15em) rotate(-60deg);
}

.ring-1>*:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(15em) rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(15em) rotate(-90deg);
}

.ring-1>*:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg) translate(15em) rotate(-120deg);
  transform: rotate(120deg) translate(15em) rotate(-120deg);
}

.ring-1>*:nth-of-type(5) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg) translate(15em) rotate(-150deg);
  transform: rotate(150deg) translate(15em) rotate(-150deg);
}

.ring-1>*:nth-of-type(6) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(15em) rotate(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(15em) rotate(-180deg);
}

.ring-1>*:nth-of-type(7) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(210deg) translate(15em) rotate(-210deg);
  transform: rotate(210deg) translate(15em) rotate(-210deg);
}

.ring-1>*:nth-of-type(8) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg) translate(15em) rotate(-240deg);
  transform: rotate(240deg) translate(15em) rotate(-240deg);
}

.ring-1>*:nth-of-type(9) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(15em) rotate(-270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(15em) rotate(-270deg);
}

.ring-1>*:nth-of-type(10) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg) translate(15em) rotate(-300deg);
  transform: rotate(300deg) translate(15em) rotate(-300deg);
}

.ring-1>*:nth-of-type(11) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg) translate(15em) rotate(-330deg);
  transform: rotate(330deg) translate(15em) rotate(-330deg);
}

.ring-1>*:nth-of-type(12) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(15em) rotate(-360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg) translate(15em) rotate(-360deg);
}

.ring-2 {
  width: 15em;
  height: 15em;
  -webkit-animation: clockwiseRotate 25s linear infinite;
  animation: clockwiseRotate 25s linear infinite;
}

.ring-2 i {
  -webkit-animation: counterClockwiseRotate 25s linear infinite;
  animation: counterClockwiseRotate 25s linear infinite;
}

.ring-2>*:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) translate(10em) rotate(-30deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg) translate(10em) rotate(-30deg);
}

.ring-2>*:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg) translate(10em) rotate(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(60deg) translate(10em) rotate(-60deg);
}

.ring-2>*:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(10em) rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(10em) rotate(-90deg);
}

.ring-2>*:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg) translate(10em) rotate(-120deg);
  transform: rotate(120deg) translate(10em) rotate(-120deg);
}

.ring-2>*:nth-of-type(5) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg) translate(10em) rotate(-150deg);
  transform: rotate(150deg) translate(10em) rotate(-150deg);
}

.ring-2>*:nth-of-type(6) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(10em) rotate(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(10em) rotate(-180deg);
}

.ring-2>*:nth-of-type(7) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(210deg) translate(10em) rotate(-210deg);
  transform: rotate(210deg) translate(10em) rotate(-210deg);
}

.ring-2>*:nth-of-type(8) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg) translate(10em) rotate(-240deg);
  transform: rotate(240deg) translate(10em) rotate(-240deg);
}

.ring-2>*:nth-of-type(9) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(10em) rotate(-270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(10em) rotate(-270deg);
}

.ring-2>*:nth-of-type(10) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg) translate(10em) rotate(-300deg);
  transform: rotate(300deg) translate(10em) rotate(-300deg);
}

.ring-2>*:nth-of-type(11) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg) translate(10em) rotate(-330deg);
  transform: rotate(330deg) translate(10em) rotate(-330deg);
}

.ring-2>*:nth-of-type(12) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(10em) rotate(-360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg) translate(10em) rotate(-360deg);
}

.ring-3 {
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  -webkit-animation: counterClockwiseRotate 20s linear infinite;
  animation: counterClockwiseRotate 20s linear infinite;
}

.ring-3 i {
  -webkit-animation: counterClockwiseRotate 20s linear infinite;
  animation: counterClockwiseRotate 20s linear infinite;
}

.ring-3>*:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) translate(5em) rotate(-30deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg) translate(5em) rotate(-30deg);
}

.ring-3>*:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg) translate(5em) rotate(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(60deg) translate(5em) rotate(-60deg);
}

.ring-3>*:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(5em) rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(5em) rotate(-90deg);
}

.ring-3>*:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg) translate(5em) rotate(-120deg);
  transform: rotate(120deg) translate(5em) rotate(-120deg);
}

.ring-3>*:nth-of-type(5) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg) translate(5em) rotate(-150deg);
  transform: rotate(150deg) translate(5em) rotate(-150deg);
}

.ring-3>*:nth-of-type(6) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(5em) rotate(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(5em) rotate(-180deg);
}

.ring-3>*:nth-of-type(7) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(210deg) translate(5em) rotate(-210deg);
  transform: rotate(210deg) translate(5em) rotate(-210deg);
}

.ring-3>*:nth-of-type(8) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg) translate(5em) rotate(-240deg);
  transform: rotate(240deg) translate(5em) rotate(-240deg);
}

.ring-3>*:nth-of-type(9) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(5em) rotate(-270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg) translate(5em) rotate(-270deg);
}

.ring-3>*:nth-of-type(10) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg) translate(5em) rotate(-300deg);
  transform: rotate(300deg) translate(5em) rotate(-300deg);
}

.ring-3>*:nth-of-type(11) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg) translate(5em) rotate(-330deg);
  transform: rotate(330deg) translate(5em) rotate(-330deg);
}

.ring-3>*:nth-of-type(12) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) translate(5em) rotate(-360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg) translate(5em) rotate(-360deg);
}

ul[class^=ring] {
  /*border: solid 1px rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.8);*/
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

ul[class^=ring] li {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1.6em;
  height: 1.6em;
  margin: -0.8em;
}


/*
  center;
*/

.orbit-center {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 2px black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}


/*.orbit-center:hover .orbit-center__icon {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
          transform: rotateZ(0deg);
}

.orbit-center__icon {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-360deg);
          transform: rotateZ(-360deg);
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}*/

.orbit-wrap>li.orbit-center:hover~li>ul {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.orbit-wrap>li.orbit-center:hover~li>ul * {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}


/* 
animations 
*/

@-webkit-keyframes clockwiseRotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes clockwiseRotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes counterClockwiseRotate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes counterClockwiseRotate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}


/* 
icons 
*/

.fa-purple {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  background: purple;
  color: white;
}

.fa-blue {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}


/*
.fa-coffee {
  background: #4CAF50;
  color: #CDDC39;
}

.fa-safari {
  background: white;
  color: darkslateblue;
}

.fa-firefox {
  background: #1565c0;
  color: #ff8f00;
}

.fa-chrome {
  background: #fbc02d;
  color: #ef6c00;
}

.fa-edge {
  background: #03a9f4;
  color: white;
}

.fa-android {
  background: snow;
  color: limegreen;
}

.fa-apple {
  background: #444;
  color: white;
}

.fa-linux {
  background: white;
  color: #222;
}

.fa-windows {
  background: white;
  color: #03a9f4;
}

.fa-terminal {
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
}

.fa-html5 {
  background: white;
  color: #e65100;
}

.fa-css3 {
  background: white;
  color: #2196f3;
}

.fa-git {
  background: #222;
  color: white;
}

.fa-free-code-camp {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

.fa-meetup {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.fa-podcast {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.fa-codepen {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="orbit">
  <ul class="orbit-wrap">
    <li class="orbit-center">
      <li>
        <ul class="ring-00">
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <ul class="ring-0">
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-purple"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-purple"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-purple"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-purple"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-purple"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-purple"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-purple"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-purple"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-purple"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-purple"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-purple"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-purple"></i></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <ul class="ring-1">
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <ul class="ring-2">
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-purple"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-purple"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-purple"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-purple"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-purple"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-purple"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-purple"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-purple"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-purple"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-purple"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-purple"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-purple"></i></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>
        <ul class="ring-3">
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
          <li><i class="orbit-icon fa fa-blue"></i></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about an easier way to create the same layout using less of code. I used CSS variable to easily control the color, dimensions of the circles and the dimension of their container.

You can of course omit the use of CSS variables by adding more classes.

```css
.ring {
  width: var(--d,100px);
  height: var(--d,100px);
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - (var(--d,100px)/2));
  left: calc(50% - (var(--d,100px)/2));
}
.clock {
  animation: clock 20s linear infinite;
}
.anti-clock {
  animation: anti-clock 20s linear infinite;
}

.orbit {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:calc(50%  - (var(--w, 15px))/2) ;
  height: var(--w, 15px);
}

.orbit:before,
.orbit:after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: var(--w, 15px);
  background:var(--c,purple);
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 0;
}

.orbit:after {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
.orbit:nth-child(2) {
  transform:rotate(90deg);
}
.orbit:nth-child(3) {
  transform:rotate(30deg);
}
.orbit:nth-child(4) {
  transform:rotate(60deg);
}
.orbit:nth-child(5) {
  transform:rotate(-30deg);
}
.orbit:nth-child(6) {
  transform:rotate(-60deg);
}

@keyframes clock {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes anti-clock {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ring clock">
  <div class="orbit"></div>
  <div class="orbit"></div>
  <div class="orbit"></div>
  <div class="orbit"></div>
  <div class="orbit"></div>
  <div class="orbit"></div>
</div>
<div class="ring anti-clock" style="--d:300px;--w:40px;--c:blue;">
  <div class="orbit"></div>
  <div class="orbit"></div>
  <div class="orbit"></div>
  <div class="orbit"></div>
  <div class="orbit"></div>
  <div class="orbit"></div>
</div>
<div class="ring clock" style="--d:400px;">
  <div class="orbit"></div>
  <div class="orbit"></div>
  <div class="orbit"></div>
  <div class="orbit"></div>
  <div class="orbit"></div>
  <div class="orbit"></div>
</div>
<div class="ring anti-clock" style="--d:600px;--w:40px;--c:blue;">
  <div class="orbit"></div>
  <div class="orbit"></div>
  <div class="orbit"></div>
  <div class="orbit"></div>
  <div class="orbit"></div>
  <div class="orbit"></div>
</div>
```